# Read images from sub folders and save into another folder

Tags: matlab

I have a code here.

```
start_path = fullfile(matlabroot, '\toolbox\images\imdemos');
% Ask user to confirm or change.
topLevelFolder = uigetdir(start_path);
if topLevelFolder == 0
    return;
end
% Get list of all subfolders.
allSubFolders = genpath(topLevelFolder);
% Parse into a cell array.
remain = allSubFolders;
listOfFolderNames = {};
while true
    [singleSubFolder, remain] = strtok(remain, ';');
    if isempty(singleSubFolder)
        break;
    end
    listOfFolderNames = [listOfFolderNames singleSubFolder];
end
numberOfFolders = length(listOfFolderNames)

% Process all image files in those folders.
for k = 1 : numberOfFolders
    % Get this folder and print it out.
    thisFolder = listOfFolderNames{k};
    fprintf('Processing folder %s\n', thisFolder);

    % Get PNG files.
    filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.png', thisFolder);
    baseFileNames = dir(filePattern);
    % Add on TIF files.
    filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.tif', thisFolder);
    baseFileNames = [baseFileNames; dir(filePattern)];
    % Add on JPG files.
    filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.jpg', thisFolder);
    baseFileNames = [baseFileNames; dir(filePattern)];
    numberOfImageFiles = length(baseFileNames);
    % Now we have a list of all files in this folder.

    if numberOfImageFiles >= 1
        % Go through all those image files.
        for f = 1 : numberOfImageFiles
            fullFileName = fullfile(thisFolder, baseFileNames(f).name);
  pathname = strcat('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\PACS_Client\\cbir_matlab\\ano\\');
  outputBaseFileName = sprintf('%3.3d.jpg',f);
  outputFullFileName = fullfile(pathname, outputBaseFileName); 

  fprintf('Processing image file %s\n', fullFileName);
  im=imread(fullFileName);
  imshow(im);
  data = im;
  imwrite(data,[pathname,outputBaseFileName]);
        end
    else
        fprintf('     Folder %s has no image files in it.\n', thisFolder);
    end
end
```

i tried to save all the images from sub folders into another folder.But could not get all the images.Only few numbers of images are saved.I want to save all the images.can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: what images are missing? are they all in the same directory or in different ones? how many folders are there?

Comment: there are 4 sub folders in the main folder.each an every sub folders have many images.i can able to save only the images which are in the first subfolder

Comment: I want save all images in the sub folders into one folder

Comment: one thing i just realized in a test is that this will only get casesensitive fileendings. like '.png' files will only work with '.png' not '.PNG' which happens sometime but that does not seem to be the primary issue here

Comment: yes. But i can able to print all the images from sub folders.But i don't know how to save those images into another folder

Comment: do you just want to copy all files to a folder or do you also want to see them/work with them in matlab?

Comment: i just want to copy all files to  folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i updated your code a bit please check if this works for you. One issue being your base file name always is '%3.3d.jpg' so every picture will be a '.jpg' even if its not. Also you are loading and showing images, but you only need to copy them, so you can go for `copyfile`. 3rd you always setting every image 001.jpg which will overwrite the the last 001.jpg from the previous folder. you have to add the number so the next folder starts with higher numbers.

```
start_path = fullfile(matlabroot, '\toolbox\images\imdemos');
% Ask user to confirm or change.
topLevelFolder = uigetdir(start_path);
if topLevelFolder == 0
    return;
end
%dir where everything should go. if the destination is not the
%topLevelFolder 
%destinationpath = strcat('D:\\pics\\');
destinationpath = topLevelFolder;

% Get list of all subfolders.
allSubFolders = genpath(topLevelFolder);
% Parse into a cell array.
remain = allSubFolders;
listOfFolderNames = {};
%while true
%    [singleSubFolder, remain] = strtok(remain, ';');
%    if isempty(singleSubFolder)
%        break;
%    end
%    listOfFolderNames = [listOfFolderNames singleSubFolder];
%end
%your while worked fine, but try to avoid 'while true' with break
for i=1:sum(strfind(allSubFolders,';'))
[singleSubFolder, remain] = strtok(remain, ';');
listOfFolderNames = [listOfFolderNames singleSubFolder];
end
numberOfFolders = length(listOfFolderNames)

%set inital count
picturecount=0;
% Process all image files in those folders.
for k = 1 : numberOfFolders
    % Get this folder and print it out.
    thisFolder = listOfFolderNames{k};
    fprintf('Processing folder %s\n', thisFolder);

    % Get PNG files.
    filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.png', thisFolder);
    baseFileNames = dir(filePattern);
    % Add on TIF files.
    filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.tif', thisFolder);
    baseFileNames = [baseFileNames; dir(filePattern)];
    % Add on JPG files.
    filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.jpg', thisFolder);
    baseFileNames = [baseFileNames; dir(filePattern)];
    numberOfImageFiles = length(baseFileNames);
    % Now we have a list of all files in this folder.

    if numberOfImageFiles >= 1
        % Go through all those image files.
        for f = 1 : numberOfImageFiles
              fullFileName = fullfile(thisFolder, baseFileNames(f).name);
              [~,~,ext] = fileparts(baseFileNames(f).name); %get extension
              outputBaseFileName = sprintf(['%3.3d' ext],f+picturecount);%create name based on picturecount
              outputFullFileName = fullfile(destinationpath, outputBaseFileName); 

              %fprintf('Processing image file %s\n', fullFileName);
              %im=imread(fullFileName);
              %imshow(im);
              %data = im;
              %imwrite(data,[pathname,outputBaseFileName]);
              %you dont need it in matlab just copy the file
              copyfile(fullFileName,outputFullFileName);
        end
        picturecount=picturecount+numberOfImageFiles;%set picturecount for next k
    else
        fprintf('     Folder %s has no image files in it.\n', thisFolder);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `baseFileNames = dir(filePattern)`, where you reset the list each time the loop is on a new folder. This is why at the end you will only have the images of the last folder. Simply add `baseFileNames = []` just before the for loop and then replace `baseFileNames = dir(filePattern)` with `baseFileNames = [baseFileNames; dir(filePattern)]`.

Comment: the ouput of dir is a struct in my version of matlab and this part works

Comment: Thank you. i tried with this. But still i cant get all images.I have 3 sub folders called folder1,folder2,folder3. It is saving only the folder 3 images .

Comment: @Jury well that is how to find the source of the problem! Read my update...